# Angular, controller without a module, unable to decipher the error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

[See the image for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uAcP.png)
`angular.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    var reg = {
        firstName: 'Aaa',
        lastName: 'Sss',
    };
    $scope.reg = reg;
    });`
This is my control.js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Script/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Script/ControllerOnly.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myController">
    FirstName <input type="text" ng-model="reg.firstName" />
     <br />    
 LastName<input type="text" ng-model="reg.lastName" />
    <br />
    <br />
    {{reg.firstName}}
    <br />
    {{reg.lastName}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html file.

Not getting the output and unable to decipher the error.
 Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance..

Comment: you are missing ng-app in the html

Comment: I tried it, still not happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the `ng-app` in the html.

Please see this working fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/r6ydu0p8/

Comment: yeah, it works perfect in jsfiddle.  I am using visual studio 2012 and here its not working.  I'm happy it worked somewhere else.  Still if I could know why its not working in VS2012 it'll be good..

Comment: hi, I had added an image, plz hav a look

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized any angular app so far. In your control.js

`myApp=angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {`

and in your HTML

`<body ng-app="myApp">`
This should solve it.. :)

Comment: Hii, I had seen examples of controllers as functions without modules.  Trying that way...

Comment: Not sure, where you came across that.. But an angular app is the starting point on any angular application.. there might be scenarios, where ng-app might not be present in the same file e.g. in case of nested views etc.
But its a must to have an angular app.. :)

Comment: I agree using the ng-app="". I did that too still did not get the result.

Comment: you have to name your app.. Did you try the code snippet, I put up earlier??? Is it not working even after that ???

Comment: plz have a look on the #1 and #2 methods for creating controllers[link](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/angularjs-101-ways-to-create-a-controller-actually-8/)

Comment: Thanks dude ... I was not aware of #1 and #2 methods .. But I still prefer the convention I wrote before, as it is explicit about what we are trying to do which gives readability to code and has less scope of errors.. Feel free to choose what suits you ... just in case try my code, and let me know if it works .. Happy coding ... :)

Comment: Hii, I also prefer the method you suggested.  Since I was exploring, I was just trying...